# On the Z80, how can we use LD instead of JR?

Tags: z80, galaksija

The [Galaksija ROM disassembly](https://www.tablix.org/~avian/galaksija/rom/rom1.html#l0fffh) has a link to **"A tutorial on how to use "ld" instructions instead of "jr" and save a few bytes in the process."**

My question is how does this work! It can see at `l038ch` it gets an address which points to executable code, and puts it on the stack, leaving a copy in HL. I can imagine that a following `RTS` would "jump" to that address, but I don't see one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the `db 1` at the end that the comment is referring to. That's the opcode for `LD BC, nnnn` without a supplied operand. So it acts to swallow the load at `l0393h`, which in turn swallows that at `l0396h`, which gets you to `PARSE` from `0392` without using a `JR` and without having done anything to change what you wanted in `HL`.

So, if you enter at `038c` then the z80 will perform:

```
LD HL, <value 1>
PUSH HL
LD L, <value 2>
LD BC, xx
LD BC, xx
(arrive at PARSE)
```

But if you enter at `0393` then instead it'll perform:

```
LD L, <value 3>
LD BC, xx
(arrive at PARSE)
```

... and if you enter at `0396`:

```
LD L, <value 4>
(arrive at PARSE)
```

The value in `HL` and `BC` when you arrive at `PARSE` depends upon the entry point, but `BC` is intentional junk. You've spent one byte on the opcode for `LD BC` in two places you'd otherwise have used a `JR`. In each of those places you've saved a byte.

Comment: Oh I see. The sacrifice is you clobber BC with garbage and it takes a bit more time, but each of those entry points, takes up a little less space.

Comment: @Wilson: It actually saves time as well as space, since the Z80 can perform an LD BC,xxxx using four cycles for the first fetch and three for each of the others.  A JR instruction takes 7 cycles to fetch the opcode and operand, but an additional 5 cycles to add the operand to the low half of the PC and then handle the possibility of carry/borrow to/from the upper half.  The only "downside" to the LD is that it loads BC with a value that is likely meaningless.

Comment: @supercat Of course, if you're going to ```POP BC``` immediately after the "load slide" then it doesn't matter anyway :-)